# Can I access exact stock count, open box, etc.?

Tags: best-buy-api

I want to create an app for Best Buy employees which enables them to use their phones to look up item data instead of making them fiddle with the nearest store computer to do that. There doesn't seem to be a method in the Best Buy API to be able to access the sort of data I want (~exact stock count, etc.). I know how to see if a store *does* or *does not* have an item in stock, but not *how many*. Would that sort of data be too "sensitive", or is there luckily some way?

Also, if I need some kind of permission to access the data in order for the app to work in a single store, who would I need to ask? The store? Or even higher up?

Comment: The question is unclear. Please provide some code or examples of what you have tried.

Comment: If the API doesn't have it then .. you don't get it via the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Best Buy APIs do not offer exact stock count for products, by store location or otherwise.